# Overlapping area from data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-analysis

I have a database containinig lots of data for each province. I'd like to know if there's a way to obtain areas of concentration of the phenomenon from the automatic overlapping of these data.

I hope to obtain areas in which the phenomenon is more or less concentrated.

I try to clarify better.
I have a single dataset with the different provinces (about 100) and in the different columns 45 variables about population, companies ...... with corresponding values for each province.
I produced the maps of the single variables and comparing the maps between them I noticed that there seem to be provinces in which all the variables are very or medium high.
I was wondering if in quantum gis there is a plugin or other that allows you to put together all the variables for each province by calculating the total intensity.
For example, in the province of Milan I have very high values for companies, for universities, for patents, for the population of a certain economic level, while for the province of Frosinone all these values are very low. I expect that the software, by combining these variables, will calculate the intensity of these variables for each province, almost overlapping the initial data.

I don't know if adding a column with the sums of the variables I could solve.
I would like the intensity of the phenomenon to emerge distinctly by groups of variables.
For example, Milan has a high value for business, university and research variables,
while it has low value for other variables such as waste, pollution and more.
The goal is to do everything automatically, if possible.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Not helpful, is it? So, if you provide some more insight on your data structure, on the "phenomenon" you want to obtain, and on your preferred software, we could help you along way better.

Comment: Hi, Erik, I try to clarify. I have a dataset ordered of 100 provinces of the same State in correspondence of each  I have 45 data about the characteristics of the population, enterprises and other…. I used quantum gis to produce maps of all the provinces for each variable. At first sight, comparing the different maps, specific areas emerge in which more phenomena have very high intensities. I was wondering if there is a plugin ot other that allows you to automatically produce these overlays. I hope it's clearer. Thanks

Comment: Nope, still not clear enough. Can you provide an example for the overlays you're trying to achieve? Also, please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/333677/edit) your question so it contains your comments, thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want QGIS to just "do statistics" for you, without you needing to really understand those statistics. I think you should ask for advise about how to do the statistical analysis on [stats.se]. Once you figure out what analysis to do, it should be simple to execute in QGIS.